# Twitter, Oauth, follow user

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

Im experimenting with twitter in c#.

The sample I am working with uses the following Oauth method to submit a new tweet:

```
string xml = _oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(
                oAuthTwitter.Method.POST,
                "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml",
                "status="+tweet);
```

How would I follow a user? Where Can I find the support for all oAuthWebRequest possibilities such as following users, checking whether a user follows me, unfollow a user.

thanks in advance

EDIT:

I tried the following as per these instructions: http://www.lordyz.co.uk/2010/10/01/c-asp-net-twitter-api-oauth-example-continued/

string friend = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ladygaga");

```
    string xml = _oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(  
    oAuthTwitter.Method.POST,  
    "http://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create/" + friend + ".xml", "");
```

This works! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use this for REST call - https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.xml
And you should send your data via POST. In your sample you are using oAuthTwitter.Method.POST, but you are sending your data in URL, not in POST.

If I understand oAuthWebRequest signature correct, then you should do something like this:

```
string friend = "ladygaga";
string xml = _oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(
                    oAuthTwitter.Method.POST, 
                    "https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.xml", 
                    "screen_name=" + friend);
```